# The following method did not exist: disableRegistry()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I use Spring Boot and MongoDB in my application. When starting the application, it gives the following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:      org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:175)
The following method did not exist:
    org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.disableRegistry()V
The method's class, org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry, is available from the following locations:
    jar:file:/C:/Users/djoni/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.37/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/Registry.class
The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
    org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry: file:/C:/Users/djoni/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.37/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar
```

Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry

I do not understand what exactly needs to be done.
I assume some versions are not compatible

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.evghenii</groupId>
    <artifactId>fitnesstudio</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fitnesstudio</name>
    <description> Spring Boot und Mongo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.37</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>            
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
             <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>  
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FitnesstudioApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FitnesstudioApplication.class, args);
    }
```

how to fix this error?

Comment: Why are you using Registry ?

Comment: Anish B.
I don’t use it, I don’t understand why he asks for it

Comment: Can you remove `extends SpringBootServletInitializer` from FitnesstudioApplication ? And Re-run the application

Comment: This is creating the issue.

Comment: deleted, nothing changed

Comment: Can you provide your code base through github ?

Comment: https://github.com/EvgheniiC/Fitnesstudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue.

Resolution : Remove the version from mongodb dependency.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Updated pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.evghenii</groupId>
    <artifactId>fitnesstudio</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fitnesstudio</name>
    <description> Spring Boot und Mongo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

      <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->

       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->

     <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->

      <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->

       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->

     <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>-->

  <!--      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>-->

     <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
<!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>-->

     <!--   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
-->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
             <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>

         <!--<dependency>
             <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId>
             <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId>
             <version>5.9.2.Final</version>
         </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

      <!--    <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

SCREENSHOT :

[image]

Note: You can see one mongodb exception. This will not come on your system as you start the mongod process on your system.